# Kerberos - multiple accounts on different subdirectories

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, asp.net-web-api, kerberos

I'm trying to implement Kerberos via Windows Integrated Auth for an internal suite of WebApi services. I've learnt a lot along the way, and understand the importance of the SPN on Kerberos.

The difficulty I'm facing is that we have multiple services (up to 30) that each have their own service account. They are hosted on different sub-directories, not as sub-domains. For example:

```
server.domain.com/reference.api
server.domain.com/client.api
```

It seems that SPN's are not compatible (by default) with my scenario. The SPN has to be registered against the netbios and FQDN of the server (server.domain.com), and only one account can be registered against each host.

What are my options?

A couple of possibilities I can think of are:

1. Using a custom service class (i.e. not HTTP), so I'd be registering an spn like so:

setspn -s referenceapi/server.domain.com domain/reference_api_user

2. Using the optional 'Service Name' or distinguished name when registering an spn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677601(v=VS.85).aspx)

The first stage of either of these possibilities is registering the SPN, which will be fairly straight-forward, but I'm not sure what we'll need to do on the client-side. As these services are all internal, we have full control over each client. We're currently using HttpClient.

Any advice? Has anyone faced a similar issue before? I can't believe I'm the first person to try and implement Kerberos across multiple services and accounts where each service is a sub-directory of the default website.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand *why* your problem is an obstacle, but a possible solution, which I used in a similar (I think) scenario is to configure a reverse-proxy. You could setup each 'subdirectory' as its own site that reverse proxies to the original location. For example, `reference.company.com` reverse proxies to `server.company.com/reference`. I may not be fully understanding the question, but I think your problem could be taken care of from the webserver layer, using IIS, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing authentication and authorization. Register one SPN, let users authenticate and create 30 windows groups, add your users and configure IIS to **authorize** those users.